# Letting users to upload files to my YouTube channel via my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube

I'm really really really new into these things.I'm willing to learn but i dont know where to start with.

What i want to do is like what my title has stated. I want to let my website users to upload to my Youtube Channel and embed the video to my website.

[The tutorial](https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide) i read was quite informative just that I don't know here should I place the php script if i want it to be on my website instead of local host.

With that,user click Upload > redirect to the upload form > upload videos to my channel > post to my website.

It would be awesome if anyone could help me out.
Thank you!!!

Comment: We (maybe) help fix code you've written. We are not here to build your system for you, or help you design it.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. I'm sorry. Thank you :)